# Axios hace la petición con https en vez de http

Tags: wordpress, axios

Estoy trabajando con axios para realizar peticiones REST a la API de Wordpress. El caso es que por algún motivo la petición que hace es https, a pesar de que la URL que le paso es http.

```
const url = constants.WORDPRESS_ROUTE + 'wp-json/wl/v1/post/home';
    axios.get(url)
     .then(res => this.setState({data: res.data}))
}
```

En principio no tiene ningún misterio. la variable `WORDPRESS_ROUTE` incluye el dominio al que hago la petición, que es http.

Comment: ¿Has verificado que la solicitud se hace realmente a `http`? Para esto usa la consola, y verifica que realmente la solicitud sale así. Es probable que el servidor al que haces la solicitud tenga configurado un `redirect` y entonces realice el enrutamiento a `https` internamente, por lo que tu solicitud será redirigida a `https` aunque la misma se haya hecho inicialmente a `http`. Eso puede ser una de las cosas que está sucediendo. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras No hay ninguna redirección HTTPs en el .htaccess, ni tiene activo un certificado SSL, pero efectivamente la petición la hace con HTTPs.

Comment: Pues no sé que podría estar pasando. Imagino que ya has depurado tu variable `WORDPRESS_ROUTE`. Otra cosa es que pruebes haciendo un `hardcode` de la ruta que pasas a axios y veas si hace lo mismo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, tuve el mismo problema y pude solucionarlo.
En mi caso era una aplicación con React y lo que hice fue quitar el siguiente fragmento del index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

espero (aunque tarde) les sirva.